# Express add backslash in insert

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working with express and Mysql trying to create a new record in my database but i'm getting one error in my console. This one show the value inside of backslash and i dont know why.

This is my function:

```
 const PostImpuestos = (data,callback) => {

var sql = "INSERT INTO tbImpuesto (nombre, valor) VALUES ?";

      connection.query(sql, [data] ,function(error,results){
        if (results){
          return callback()
        } else {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
    }
```

and this is the error:

> sqlMessage:
>      'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'`nombre` = \'Impuesto de Tijuana\', `valor` = \'15%\'\' at line 1',
>     sqlState: '42000',
>     index: 0,
>     sql:
>      'INSERT INTO tbImpuesto (nombre, valor) VALUES `nombre` = \'Impuesto de Tijuana\', `valor` = \'15%\'' }

I was thinking the error could be something about type of the value data, because this is a json. I change it for array and object but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix you've got your insert query wrong you need to add ? for each variable you insert inside of brackets.

`INSERT INTO tbImpuesto (nombre, valor) VALUES (?, ?);`

The backslashes are just sanitzation to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the data variable? Because I feel like your putting an array inside of an array

Comment: Yea, you'll need to replace [data] with [name, value] when performing the query